# Efficient way to compare actual data to data model?

Tags: python, dataframe, performance, data-cleaning

I have a python process that pulls data from multiple sources (APIs, files, DBs) and inserts to our own DB. As part of the process, I compare the incoming data to the mapped table metadata to check for data type mismatches, data length issues, converting true/false to 1/0, documenting when new columns are added/removed, etc. It logs all these issues in a separate table for remediation.

The code I have is working fine, but it is not the most efficient with the volume of data we are receiving (~6m records a day between all sources). Depends on data size, but can take up to 60seconds for a list of 50k records / 300 cols each.

Currently I am taking the incoming data as a list of dicts [{},{}], looping through each dict, then each key/value pair to map to mapped metadata.

Is there an efficient way to do this via dataframes or something else? Has anyone else built something similar?

Can share code if needed

Comment: The question is too abstract to give a meaningful answer. Can you give more specifics?

Comment: yes,  there may be a more efficient way with dataframes,  what have you tried so far ?